# Getting the onClickListener registered for an element

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Is it possible to get the `onClickListener`s registered for an element in a browser DOM?

If yes how does one do that?

Comment: `onClickListener` is a Java thing.  Did you mean to tag your question with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the method `addEventListener()` from DOM interface `Event Target` ??

This is the syntax

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener);
```

Where **target** is mostly `window`, `document`, and an Element (`document.querySelector('#item')` for example )...

The **type** is where you specify the `'click'` representing the event type

and the **listener** is the callback function you will use